# How to embed iframe from website in QML (Qt) application?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Just upgraded to Qt Creator 5.4.1 and am very sad to see the html property is deprecated in their WebView data model.

Normally I would just embed api code from my desired website and paste that into the html property of a webview.  Something like what we see below:

```
<iframe name="puzzle" src="http://www.chessgames.com/puzzle.html"
width="296" height="448" hspace="0" vspace="0" marginwidth="0"
marginheight="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Since the html property is deprecated, I am mystified on how to embed an iframe into QML.

I tried using WebView's url property, but that brings me the entire webpage.  I just want the iframe and for it to scale properly (i.e. not show up extremely small or extremely big).

The following works and it shows the iframe, but it is surrounded by whitespace (i.e. the other parts of the website).

```
            WebView
        {
            id: webview
            url: "http://www.chessgames.com/puzzle.html"

            width: (getBackgroundHeight() * 0.33) * 0.66
            height: getBackgroundHeight() * 0.33

            onNavigationRequested:
            {
                // detect URL scheme prefix, most likely an external link
                var schemaRE = /^\w+:/;

                if (schemaRE.test(request.url))
                    request.action = WebView.AcceptRequest;
                else
                {
                    request.action = WebView.IgnoreRequest;
                    // delegate request.url here
                }
            }
        }
```

Does anyone know how to embed an iframe using QML?

Comment: If the html property was working for you previously, why not just use this method? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebkit-webview.html#loadHtml-method

Comment: Where would I call that?  I can't call that property directly inside the WebView data model because it's function.  Right now I'm calling a Javascript function inside of webview that calls webview.loadhtml...but I'm not sure where to put the javascript function.  I stuck in in the height property for now because it needs a property bind to, which is stupid. :(